# Acquire arrays if compatible only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a query where I can return only the arrays that match the parameter I'm sending. Currently, it returns all the arrays if at least one matches. I tried several things but I have not had the expected result. Here's the last code I tried:

```
const documents = await DocumentsUser.find({ 'documents.files.drive': 'Admissions' })
```

Json object:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5f15cc4b22da606dfb69337d"
   },
   "objectId":{
      "$oid":"5e9f278ec06d92327c9505d5"
   },
   "type":"student",
   "documents":[
      {
         "files":[
            {
               "first":false,
               "document":"Certificado de admisión",
               "description":"revision",
               "drive":"Admissions1",
               "name":"Admissions/1588820752808-logo.png",
               "approvers":[
                  {
                     "status":"Submitted"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "first":false,
               "document":"Certificación",
               "description":"Prueba de certificación",
               "drive":"Admissions",
               "name":"Admissions/1588871305807-Application Sample1.pdf",
               "approvers":[
                  {
                     "status":"Submitted"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5f2044e09992a1f5a9fb75ce"
   },
   "objectId":{
      "$oid":"5e9f27b2c06d92327c9505d6"
   },
   "type":"school",
   "documents":[
      {
         "files":[
            {
               "first":false,
               "document":"Certificado de admisión",
               "description":"revision",
               "drive":"otro",
               "name":"Admissions/1588820752808-logo.png",
               "approvers":[
                  {
                     "status":"Submitted"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "first":false,
               "document":"Certificación",
               "description":"Prueba de certificación",
               "drive":"Admissions",
               "name":"Admissions/1588871305807-Application Sample1.pdf",
               "approvers":[
                  {
                     "status":"Submitted"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: If I put "Admissions" I want to return only the array or arrays that have within documents->file->drive only the ones that match, in that json should return only the array that has the match the other should not appear in the result @MontgomeryWatts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

The aggregation pipeline may look like this:

```
DocumentsUser.aggregate([
  { $match: { 'documents.files.drive': 'Admissions' }},
  { $unwind: "$documents" },
  { $unwind: "$documents.files" },
  { $match: { 'documents.files.drive': 'Admissions' }},
])
```

As is, this will give you the whole document. If you want just the `files` field you can add a `$project` stage at the end like so:

```
{ $project: { "_id": 0, "documents.files": "$documents.files" }}
```